# How to write more than one variable in a text file - Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, passwords

I am trying to create a Password Generator. The program is supposed to generate a List of random passwords and then write them to a `.txt` file. With the code below, the program is only writing the last password generated, rather than all of them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import random

#The Characters List
Characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()_+-=[];'\,./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

#Password Generator

#Get the Input form the User
Length = input("Password Length > ")
Length = int(Length)

#Get the Input form the User
PasswordNumber = input("Number of Passwords > ")
PasswordNumber = int(PasswordNumber)

for p in range(PasswordNumber):
    Password = ""
    for i in range(Length):
        Password += random.choice(Characters)
    print(Password)

f= open("PasswordList.txt","w+")
f.write(Password)
f.close()
```

My results:

```
Password Length > 10
Number of Passwords > 5
LgoQ$i%e_O
![i/NxsqQr
n-ydWA/9.5
ksI,jg]#8q
![xrU#=2@#
```

But when I open the "PasswordList.txt" the text that is inside is only: `![xrU#=2@#`, the last password it generated. 
Also I want the passwords to have the same format as seen on the terminal:

```
LgoQ$i%e_O
![i/NxsqQr
n-ydWA/9.5
ksI,jg]#8q
![xrU#=2@#
```

and not like this:

```
LgoQ$i%e_O![i/NxsqQrn-ydWA/9.5ksI,jg]#8q![xrU#=2@#
```

Comment: add the file open, write and close statements inside the for loop to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get only one password because that's what you told it to do: generate and print out all the passwords.  Once they're all generated, *then* you write only one password to the file.

You need to pull that print statement into your loop:

```
f = open("PasswordList.txt","w+")

for p in range(PasswordNumber):
    Password = ""
    for i in range(Length):
        Password += random.choice(Characters)
    print(Password)

    f.write(Password + "\n")

f.close()
```

To get the same format, simply add a newline to each `write`, or use the `writeln` method.

Sample output, with 10 passwords of length 8:

```
w@wz+]S2
8t=G#r,F
H$aITs0&
=dMbird6
Y)Dpu]EZ
K\ZDNI*M
L6(2L_7_
VJL3GxF$
.nRt!XIa
=OXP8=aC
```